# Swift delegate not calling function in parent

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to get a child view controller, which is displayed in a view container at the bottom part of the main, parent View Controller. When I press the button in the child, "Button pressed from Basic VC" prints to the console, but "Warm button pressed from main VC" does not. I need the function that prints that second message to be called in the main View Controller. Here is the relevant BasicViewController code:

```
protocol BasicVCDelegate: class {
    func warmButton()
}

class BasicViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var BasicVCDelegate: BasicVCDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var warmButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func warmButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Button pressed from Basic VC")
        BasicVCDelegate?.warmButton()
    }
}
```

And from ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, BasicVCDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        pauseButton.isEnabled = false

        hideAll();
        self.basicContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        self.basicContainer.isHidden = false;

        self.timerLabel.text = String("00:00:00");

        eventTable.dataSource = self
        eventTable.delegate = self

        loadEvents(event: "timer start")
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // CREATE SEGUEs
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let classBasicVC = nav.topViewController as? BasicViewController {
            classBasicVC.BasicVCDelegate = self
        }
    }

    // FUNCTIONS FOR BASIC VIEW CONTROLLER TO REFERENCE
    func warmButton() {
        print("Warm button pressed from main VC")
    }
}
```

EDIT:
From everyone below, it seems that the following section of code in ViewController is causing the issue (the line within the if statement is never being called):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let classBasicVC = nav.topViewController as? BasicViewController {
        classBasicVC.basicVCDelegate = self
    }
}
```

This is probably due to my unfamiliarity with delegates and the prepareforsegue function. Need help figuring out what should follow that "if let"

EDIT 2:
Replaced the above code with the following as per some users' suggestion (still not reaching the print statement):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? BasicViewController, let classBasicVC = nav.basicVCDelegate {
        print("got here!!")
    }
}
```

FINAL EDIT:
Thank you for your help! After some playing around, the following works (aside from a warning that changes to an error when I address it - I can live with a warning).

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? BasicViewController, let classBasicVC = nav as? BasicViewController? {
        classBasicVC?.basicVCDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `classBasicVC.BasicVCDelegate = self` do you see that it is actually called?

Comment: this tutorial work in Push but also work in the present : https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/11/what-is-protocol-how-to-pop-data-using.html When you present then classBasicVC.BasicVCDelegate = self do.

Comment: FYI - It's standard practice to name variables and methods starting with lowercase letters. Class and struct names start with uppercase letters. You should properly name your delegate property.

Comment: Try to debug and check if your program in entering in the if let in the prepare for segue method, just to be sure that you are setting the delegate properly.

If that does not work, change the name of the delegate to a different one from the type of the protocol, or call it like this (with self):

self.BasicVCDelegate?.warmButton()

Comment: I fixed the name as rmaddy suggested. I used some break points as @Allen R suggested to confirm that if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let classBasicVC = nav.topViewController as? BasicViewController { is actually called, but classBasicVC.basicVCDelegate = self is not

Comment: Looks like the cast from `let classBasicVC = nav.topViewController as? BasicViewController` is failing the cast then. Must not be the top ViewController as I am not sure that segue would add it there.

Comment: @AllenR I don't completely understand the syntax here, was following a tutorial online. Seems weird that nav.topViewController would be defined as a BasicViewController which is the child VC. Any idea how I might be able to make it right?

Comment: maybe you are not presenting navigation controller but the BasicViewController itself

Comment: @Tj3n edited the code as per your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It should be this instead of your last edited code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let classBasicVC = segue.destination as? BasicViewController {
        classBasicVC.basicVCDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned button's delegate to the ViewController

Add this to your ViewController's `viewDidLoad`

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    //other code 
    yourButton.BasicVCDelegate = self
    }
```

Also its a good practice to use camel case for delegate variable like this `basicVCDDelegate`